# How to separate test plans

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have 2 non-related projects, being managed by the same group of developers.

Is there anyway to separate test plans in different projects-not only by user?

which is the best practice if I am managing 2 testing projects?

Comment: @antu it is a perfect valid question that was successfully answered, I ave already read the documentation they provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to separate test plans in different projects-not only by user?

If you want to have them completely separate then check-out https://github.com/kiwitcms/tenants. This will allow you to define tenants (per team or per project/product) which have their own DB schema and domain namespace. All of this works only with PostgreSQL and is fairly new so you will be mostly on your own.

Otherwise if you trust your team mates then just use a single instance for all teams/products.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/testplan.html

You simply add multiple projects. When creating a new test plan assign it to appropriate product.